# strange leading "f" when print out a char

Tags: c, printf

Hi guys, I wrote the following code:

```
union endian {
    char a;
    int  b;
} test;
char c;

test.b = 0xaabbccdd;
c =  (char)test.a;
printf("0x%x\n", c);
printf("0x%x\n", test.b);
printf("0x%x\n", test.a);
printf("0x%x\n", (char)test.a);
```

But the output is:

```
0xffffffdd
0xaabbccdd
0xffffffdd
0xffffffdd
```

I want to know why there is some leading `0xffffff` before the char variable.

Comment: It is a signed char, try changing to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 4):

`%x` interprets its argument as an *`unsigned int`*. Integers passed into a variadic function are always promoted to `int`, so your signed `char` values are being promoted to signed `int`s using sign extension, then interpreted as `unsigned int` by `%x`.

You can work around this by casting to an `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.

Comment: The values are not being promoted. The c run-time is looking through to the bytes beyond the variable when you pass a variable that's not large enough.

Comment: @user814064: They are actually being promoted (up-converted). See, for example, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic (yes, it's a C++ reference, but I can't link you the C99 standard at the moment).

Comment: @user814064, It's a rule of passing things as variadic arguments.

Comment: C99 spec: 6.5.2.2/7: "The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.". 6.5.2.2/6: "the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument promotions". 6.3.1.1/2: "If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions."

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected `FFFFFFFF` comes from converting the `char` to an `int` via sign extension.  The variadic parameters, the ones after the format parameter in printf(const char *format, ...), are convert to `int` (if of a smaller integer type) or `double` (if a float).

Recommend:

Rather than printing the numeric value of `c` or `test.a` with the unmodified format specifier `%x`,  (meant for `int`) use the modifier `hh`.

```
printf("0x%hhx\n", c);
```

This will print out 2 hexadecimal digits after the `0x`.

---

Ref C11 7.21.6.1 7 "hh Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a signed char or unsigned char argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to signed char or unsigned char before printing);"